# C# Use base class property value in a derived class property override

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

My class structure is as follows:

```
public class Animal
{
    private int _animalId;

    public virtual int AnimalId
    {
        get { return _animalId; }
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override int AnimalId
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (Request.Params["New_Animal"] == "true")
                return -1;
            else
                return AnimalId;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to override the `AnimalId` property as follows:
if it is a new animal the id should be -1, but if we are updating an existing animal I would like to return the `AnimalId` from the base class.

This is an extremely simplified example, but I'm wondering if / how this can be done.

Thanks

Comment: `_animalId` should probably be protected and not private

Comment: return base.AnimalId;

Comment: When you say you want to update an existing animal, do you mean to retrieve it from a database? Or do you mean that after a property is changed, the animal is no longer new and so therefore you want it to no longer have an Id of -1?

Comment: @JonathanWalton update as in retrieve the record from database and update the data, and new as in inserting a new record into the database

Comment: it sounds a little bit like inheritance is not the correct approach for you. Are you counting the animals? sounds like you need a static variaable

Comment: @MongZhu as I stated in my question, this is an extremely simplified example, but I will look into it and see if that is a viable option.

Comment: thanks @yW0K5o, `base.AnimalId` is what I needed.

Comment: what is the inheritance relationship good for ? I don't understand the connection to the database records

Comment: My page must inherit from the parent because there are many other methods and properties that are used. Once I'm already inheriting why should I create my own independent static property which will be using a value from the parent page.

Comment: ok now the picture gets clearer in my mind. Ok then my comment is useless. thanx for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use base.AnimalId

```
public class Animal
{
    private int _animalId;

    public virtual int AnimalId
    {
        get { return _animalId; }
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override int AnimalId
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (Request.Params["New_Animal"] == "true")
                return -1;
            else
                return base.AnimalId;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the animalId in animal private protected and in dog you can then return base.animalid in the property